# Windows Store App Content PlaceHolder XAML

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

I'm creating a Windows Store app that has a split layout. The top-half shows a Bing Map with the current position of the user. The bottom half shows several buttons to control the application. In short the application records a
track and the buttons in the lower half store settings during the track. There are several different layouts needed for the bottom half. The number of buttons and the actions are all the same only the position and layout of the buttons change.

I'm therefore looking for some sort of ContentPlaceHolder that can inject the XAML based on the preferences set by the user. I've looked at ContentPresenters and ContentControls but I just can't get it right. Is such thing even possible?

Comment: Can you just use a Grid? You can dynamically add the buttons you need as children of the grid, or you could make UserControls for the various layouts.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions available. If I understand correctly, you have a fixed set of possible "layouts".

I would probably create a templated Control ([CustomControl](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/10/15/building-a-custom-control-using-xaml-and-c.aspx) with different [Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465374.aspx) and a [TemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx) or VisualStates).

More simple option would be to just place the different layouts there and switch their visibility.

Last, you could just create different UserControls and place them by code.

FYI: ContentPresenter is used to place the Content inside of a ControlTemplate/ContentTemplate. ContentControl provides a Template of a specific Content and is the Base for most custom Controls/UserControls.